# Infinitely running Laravel - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

A class in PHP needs to be called infinitely after each execution. That class executes and does the job in 4 seconds or more, finish time could vary in seconds depending on the task gathering(GPS coordinates) but it always finishes up nicely without any crash. I have built the above task with JQUERY and Ajax and it works fine.

However, I am working with Laravel now and have thought about implementing Laravel CRON now but so far I have only encountered limitation with Laravel CRON.

They mention all task run time to be linked with minutes,hours,days,weeks,month but doesn't not mention execution depending on successful completion of the first task. As I would like to execute the same class again and again but not halting the current execution.

Does Laravel have this limitation or I am missing something.

Comment: Does this has some condition to run or something? i.e. : new coordinates in some database table or something

Comment: Then its not a CRON job its a permanantly running batch job

Comment: Sounds like a jobs for [queue's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#retrying-failed-jobs). Remember that PHP is not designed with continuesly running in mind.

Comment: @aaron0207  yes, the class calls/connects to the GPS tracker which produces GPS coordinates in a JSON formated file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is it possible for me to write a batch which will execute the same class infinitely but always wait for the previous execution to finish properly before executing new instance of the same class. Any directions if possible ?

Comment: @ThomasMoors I agree with your statement but don't have much option on the table at the moment. I need to try and build something with what I know for the time being.

Comment: What about use node.js? You can fire Laravel events by calling a route from node and you can use your actual script or adapt it

Comment: @aaron0207 sure looking into it now.